# DateTime.ParseExact to NodaTime ZonedDateTime issue

Tags: c#, nodatime

I'm having an issue converting a parsed `string` into a correct NodaTime `ZonedDateTime`. The below method takes a string (allegedly in UTC) pushed by the brokers server, and returns a `ZonedDateTime` with the `DateTimeZone` being set to UTC. The domain model will only accept `ZonedDateTime` objects so this is happening at the system boundary.

For example, a `string` being passed as the argument being exactly '2017060623:20:10' would then return a `ZonedDateTime` like 2017-06-06T13-:20:10 (curiously a ten hour difference, my local time zone here in Sydney is +10 UTC).

```
public static ZonedDateTime GetZonedDateTimeUtcFromMarketDataString(string dateTime)
{
    var dotNetDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(
        dateTime,
        "yyyyMMddHH:mm:ss,                
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
        .ToUniversalTime();

    return new ZonedDateTime(Instant.FromDateTimeUtc(dotNetDateTime), DateTimeZone.Utc);
}
```

So I changed the method to the below, which works, but I'm sure there's a better way. I'm certain my error is that I'm somehow involving my local time zone, rather than keeping everything in UTC.

```
public static ZonedDateTime GetZonedDateTimeUtcFromMarketDataString(string dateTime)
{
    var parsedDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(
        dateTime,
        "yyyyMMddHH:mm:ss",
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    var dotNetDateTime = new DateTime(
        parsedDateTime.Year,
        parsedDateTime.Month,
        parsedDateTime.Day,
        parsedDateTime.Hour,
        parsedDateTime.Minute,
        parsedDateTime.Second,
        DateTimeKind.Utc);

    return new ZonedDateTime(Instant.FromDateTimeUtc(dotNetDateTime), DateTimeZone.Utc);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest not using `DateTime` at all. You're using Noda Time - so go all in :)

To parse text as a `ZonedDateTime`, you use a `ZonedDateTimePattern`. Here's an example:

```
using System;
using NodaTime;
using NodaTime.Text;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string text = "2017060623:20:10";
        Console.WriteLine(GetZonedDateTimeUtcFromMarketDataString(text));

    }

    static readonly ZonedDateTimePattern ParsePattern =
        ZonedDateTimePattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture(
           "yyyyMMddHH:mm:ss",
           DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb); // Won't actually be used...

    static ZonedDateTime GetZonedDateTimeUtcFromMarketDataString(string dateTime)
        => ParsePattern.Parse(dateTime).Value;
}
```

The default template value already uses UTC as a time zone, so you don't need to worry about that.

Alternatively, you could use a `LocalDateTimePattern` given that the text you're using doesn't specify a time zone - parse to a `LocalDateTime` and then call `LocalDateTime.InUtc()`.

All of this raises another question though, which is why you're parsing the value to a `ZonedDateTime` at all. If you've *always* got a UTC value, do you really need it to be a `ZonedDateTime` rather than an `Instant`? You don't know the time zone the value was originally observed in, so it feels more like a point in time to me.

Comment: Ah yes, I knew there was a way to cut out the BCL middle man and hand the string directly to NodaTime. Admittedly I was hacking away just to get something to work initially and grabbed hold of that Instant.FromDateTimeUtc() to convert it. 

I agree that Instant could work and represents time unambiguously (initially I implemented NodaTime using Instant throughout the code base) then decided for compliance, ISO 8601 standardization, and the fact that the time is indeed UTC - to go with ZonedDateTime. I'm injecting a ZonedClock with my own interface throughout the system instance too. Tx!

Answer (score 1):

The `DateTime.ParseExact` function can take [DateTimeStyle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91hfhz89(v=vs.110).aspx) as a parameter.

Try this

```
var parsedDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(
    dateTime,
    "yyyyMMddHH:mm:ss",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
    DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal | DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
```

Comment: Great, worked like a charm and much better code. Thanks, James (I up-voted which should show once my rep is >= 15)

Comment: While this will work, it seems unnecessary to use two different date/time APIs, when Noda Time provides everything required here.